# Can I set the command function for a tkinter scale later on in the code?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I want to define a `tk.Scale` widget and assing the command function LATER ON. I'm think of something similar to scale.set() but for the command option. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly all options of all widgets can be configured at any time via the `configure` and `config` methods (one is a synonym for the other).

scale = tk.Scale(...)
...
scale.configure(command=the_command)